# BrowserfieldDemo application not executing on blackberry device

Tags: java, blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem executing browserfield with “;deviceside=true” on BlackBerry sim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736119/problem-executing-browserfield-with-deviceside-true-on-blackberry-sim)

The BrowserFieldDemo application from sample eclipse plugin is executing fine of 4.7 storm simulator,but when i use it in the device 9550 storm,it doesn't execute.At the top buffering is going on,but only white screen is displayed,the actual web page is not displayed.I tried appending ";interface=wifi" or ";deviceside=true" or even ";interface=tru" to the URL,but nothing seem to be fruitful.Can anyone help me.Its urgent.Where i am actually doing the mistake.

Comment: You've asked the exact same question twice.  This is rude.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736119/problem-executing-browserfield-with-deviceside-true-on-blackberry-sim

Comment: Oh srryyy,but i dont know the rules fully.

Comment: actually sir i am in need of help,its urgent,just hoping smeone will come up

Answer (score 0):

since 5.0  there is BrowserField component

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html

This is much more better then old browser in BrowerFieldDemo, you should try...

Comment: Thank you Janci,but actually i need to build my application that should support from 4.6.0 OS,so i cant use the BrowserField component here.I have implemented the browserfield using the samples of eclipse plugin.Its executing fine on simulator when i launch MDS.But when i execute on device it only displays a white blank page.I have tried appending ";deviceside=true" and ";interface=wifi" to the url,but both dont solve the issue,Any idea?

Comment: well in my case adding  ";deviceside=true" worked, is it woking on 5.0 emulator?

Comment: thnak u Janci again for taking your time to reply,i run it on 5.0 and its not executing.Its the same sample code from the eclipse samples names BrowserFieldDemo.Did you execute this project in ur device?

Comment: BrowserFieldDemo has three classes-BrowserFieldDEmo,Utilities,SecondaryResourceFetchThread.Its running well with MDS,but as soon as i stop MDS,and add ";deviceside=true" and try to run,it only displays white screen.